# User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-runner:default" cannot list resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace "gitlab-runner"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to setup gitlab runner with my aws eks cluster. I have been able to create the namesapces without any problem. However, when I trigger the gitlab cicd pipeline I get the below error.

`ERROR: Error retrieving events list: events is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-runner:default" cannot list resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace "gitlab-runner"`.

Here is my gitlab-runner-role.yaml file

```
piVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner
  namespace: gitlab-runner
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods", "pods/exec", "pods/log", "pods/attach", "secrets", "events"]
    verbs: ["list", "get", "watch", "create", "delete", "update"]
```

Any help on why I am getting this error and how I can fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be something new with GitLab 16.2 - we didn't have this problem before we upgraded the runners to the latest version.

For our runners, I just added "events" to our helm chart values file (the rbac - rules - resources section) and did a `helm upgrade` to apply the changes.

Answer (score 1):

need to create binding to attach service account to role

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner-rolebinding
  namespace: gitlab-runner
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: gitlab-runner
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: gitlab-runner
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

you can check via

`kubectl auth can-i list events --as=system:serviceaccount:default:gitlab-runner`

Answer (score 0):

This error also get when we can't access the cluster with given **Kubeconfig**. In my scenario, Kubeconfig value is accessed via variable in pipeline.

In my case I was testing my pipeline in my working branch. I have put base64 encoded Kubeconfig file as a CI/CD variables and have put the `protect variable` flag for that variable. Since my feature branch wasn't a `protected branch`, I got this error. Once I remove this flag or update my feature branch to protected branch, this was fixed.

Remove the `Protect variable` flag from below. You can get these by *Project>>Settings>>CI/CD>>* and edit the relevant variable.

[image: Edit variable in Gitlab CI/CD]

or make your branch protected. To do that go to *Project>>Settings>>Repository>>Protected branches* and add your branch with relevant permissions. Once your testing done and merge remove the feature/working branch from protected branches.

[image: Gitlab protected branches]

I recommend option 2 as it is more secured and easy to maintain.